# SQL Server object dependencies - sys.sql_expression_dependencies

Tags: sql-server

Does `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` cover just dependencies inside object definitions excluding keys/relationship references?

I'm looking to list all dependencies where for example a view, function etc have another object as part of the definition e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW v_a
AS
SELECT *
FROM t_a
JOIN t_b on k_c = k_d
```

I want to list all of the references from v etc, but not t_a -> t_b
e.g.

| Referenced | Referencing |
| --- | --- |
| t_a | v |
| t_b | v |

& not

| Referenced | Referencing |
| --- | --- |
| t_a | v |
| t_b | v |
| t_a | t_b |

Thanks

Comment: I think sys.sql_expression_dependencies already works like that. The view (v_a) references both t_a and t_b, and that is what is shown on the system table. Unless somehow the table t_b references the table t_a, that relationship wouldn't show.

Comment: Extending @BrianStork's comment, can you come up with an example where it works the way you're describing? `create table`, `create view` statements along with a select from `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`.

Comment: The way you want it to work is how it works, usually one wants the other way, and that's very complicated :)

Comment: Thanks both - it seemed to be working like that, but the docs weren't specific.